# Ajax and Dojo Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I've been looking into the javascript package Dojo, and I noticed that it uses sort of its own form of Ajax, but as far as I can tell it does the same things as standard Ajax.  Is there a benefit to using either over the other, or is there really a difference?

I'm new to both Ajax and Dojo so feel free to correct anything I may have said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of the Dojo description sums up the benefit: "Dojo saves you time."

You can code all of your AJAX functionality by hand, or you can use a framework (Dojo, jQuery, Prototype, etc) to take care of a lot of the mundane tasks for you.

*Edit:*

For a good list of reasons to use Dojo or something similar, please see: [6 Reasons To Use JavaScript Libraries & Frameworks](http://davidwalsh.name/6-reasons-to-use-javascript-libraries-frameworks).

Comment: So basically you're saying that Dojo's AJAX capabilities, as well as anything else like it such as jQuery, make it so you essentially have less AJAX code to write because alot of the code is built in?

Comment: @portugusto_programmer: Precisely.

Comment: @portugusto_programmer, also Dojo is cross-browser, so that the same call works the same in every browser from IE6 to FF to Chrome to Safari and others.  If you code raw Ajax, you have to handle differences between browsers and bugs in different browser versions.

Answer (score 0):

Like other libraries and frameworks for client-side web applications, Dojo provides a **wrapper** around the native browser ajax capabilities.  Ultimately it can only do what the browsers will allow. It can, however, make things a little more convenient, in a way similar to that by which php makes assembly language programming more convenient.